# Discord.py Bot - What is the difference between `if` command and `async def`?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have seen many developers coding their python bots for Discord in 2 ways.

Some of them use:

```py
if message.content.startswith("command"):
    await message.channel.send("text")
```

And others (majority) use this method:

```py
@client.command()
async def command(ctx):
    response = "Text"
    await ctx.send(response)
```

What is the difference between them two and which method is better/ more productive to use?

Comment: I have seen guides that use the first and guides that use the latter, I think the second one is a more "pythonic" way to do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Using `@client.command()` and `async def` means those are callable functions inside of a `coroutine`, whereas the `if`, I think, would require nesting in some kind of loop.

When you `client.RUN(TOKEN)` to start up your bot, the Discord module starts up an `asyncio coroutine`. It uses `async` and `await` to allow asynchronous task management, see [the Python documentation on coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutine) and the [Discord.py API Reference on wait_for events](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)

Comment: `if` would need to be in the message handler